# onTouchEnd not working for Android Froyo 2.2?

Tags: javascript, android

The following html when opened in the default browser on Android 2.2 registers touchstart and touchmove events properly, but not touchend events.  Any idea why?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="a" onTouchStart="touchstartFunction(event);"
            onTouchMove="touchmoveFunction(event);"
            onTouchEnd="touchendFunction(event);"
            style="width:300px ; height:300px;background:red;"></div>
<script>
    function touchstartFunction(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var touch = event.touches[0];
        document.getElementById('touchMoveTextbox').value = "Touch start at " + touch.pageX + "x" + touch.pageY;
    }
    function touchmoveFunction(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var touch = event.touches[0];
        document.getElementById('touchMoveTextbox').value = "Touch move at " + touch.pageX + "x" + touch.pageY;
    }
    function touchendFunction(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var touch = event.touches[0];
        document.getElementById('touchMoveTextbox').value = "Touch end at " + touch.pageX + "x" + touch.pageY;
    }
</script>
<input type='textbox' size="30" id='touchMoveTextbox' >
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Believe you might be experiencing this:
[touchend event doesn't work on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987706/touchend-event-doesnt-work-on-android)

because you access touches[0] which is empty in the last case and causing a javascript error.