# Touchend and Sliding Finger Off Button

Tags: touch, multi-touch, android-browser

I've got a volume buttons that bind to the the touchstart and mousedown events, and the touchend and mouseup events (I've also tried touchleave and touchcancel).

When the user has their finger held on the button and lifts their finger it calls the end handler as expected. However if the user slides their finger off the button and then lifts their finger the event never gets fired (which causes a problem of an infinitely decrementing or incrementing volume control).

I've tried binding the touchend event to the window object, that doesn't seem to do anything. Here's what I have at the moment:

```
$('#volume-wrap button').on('touchstart mousedown', function() {
    if (this.id == 'volume-down')
        volume_timer = setInterval(function(){main.hud.adjustVolume('down')}, 100);
    else
        volume_timer = setInterval(function(){main.hud.adjustVolume('up')}, 100);
});

$(window).on('touchend mouseup', function() {
    if (volume_timer) {
        clearInterval(volume_timer);
        volume_timer = 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding e.preventDefault() to the touchstart event. 
There is a bug in the android browser.

see: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4549

Update:
For a better explanation see SystemParadox answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11613327/757086