# Javascript error for my_title.innerHTML on android 2.3

Tags: javascript, android, html, dom

I was using `my_title.innerHTML = "blah"`, which failed on my android 2.3.

Although I have fixed it by using jquery(...).html( 'blah'),

my question is: Why did the android 2.3 machine fail where pc browsers AND a new android (my co-worker's) succeeded?

---

*I want to know this because it will help me understand the android browser environment.*

Comment: the error will tell itself if you print stack trace for both scenerios

Comment: in pc browsers the my_title.innerHTML was successfully setting the title (the browser tab would show the correct text).

Comment: ok check these two links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314886/how-can-i-debug-javascript-on-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987706/touchend-event-doesnt-work-on-android may be it will be helful for you also please check the same page for different versions of android