# Touchend doesnt work, even after calling e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript

Ok I am in a big predicament.

I stumbled across the touchend bug. After touchmove the touchend event doesnt work, no matter what I do.

I tried adding `preventDefault()` within touchmove. I also tried to replace touchend with touchcancel. It all fails. I did that read that this is related to scrolling in touch enabled devices but I didnt find any working solution so far.

I know this could be solved with JQuery but I prefer doing this the Vanilla JS way so that I can learn whats going on under the hood.

```
var touchActive = false;

elem.addEventListener("touchstart", function (event) {
    touchActive = true;
});
elem.addEventListener("touchend", function (event) {
    touchActive = false;
});
elem.addEventListener("touchmove", function (event) {
    if(touchActive){
    }
    else{
    }
});
```

So why doesnt touchend work?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? If you put a `console.log` inside the listener nothing will log?
If it does fire, then it seems like you're expecting `touchmove` to keep firing even after `touchend` has been.

Comment: @Zirak used an alert box. Nothing happens.

Comment: I sort of have a hard time believing that under regular circumstances `touchend` doesn't fire. Can you write a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce on my phone which is running Marshmallow (6.0.1. I never thought I'd say a sentence like that). Yikes, that's a nasty bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android < 6.0 then you will be forced to use both touchstart and touchmove events or ending events wont be possible unless you are thinking of integrating preventDefault. The latter might affect your scrolling so here is my solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/z9p7uxp2/

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].addEventListener("touchend", function (event) {
    x.style.background = "black"
});
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].addEventListener("touchcancel", function (event) {
    x.style.background = "black"
});
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].addEventListener("touchmove", function (event) {
    x.style.background = "red"
});
```

Comment: This "you need touchstart to have touchend events" seems to be true case with desktop Chrome simulating touch screen. Do you have any offical docs for this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate your scenario with the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <style type="text/css">
        #foobar {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: red;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="foobar"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var touchActive = false;

        var elem = document.getElementById("foobar")

        elem.addEventListener("touchstart", function (event) {
            console.log("Touch Start");
            touchActive = true;
        });
        elem.addEventListener("touchend", function (event) {
            console.log("Touch End");
            touchActive = false;
        });
        elem.addEventListener("touchmove", function (event) {
            console.log("Touch Active: %s", (touchActive) ? "Yes" : "No")
            if(touchActive){
            }
            else{
            }
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I had no issues with the touchstart/touchend using the iOS Simulator. So, a few things.

1. Is it necessary to track touchstart/touchend on a mobile device when touchmove is only going to be dispatched when somebody is actively touching the device?
2. More of a UX issue -- be careful about preventDefault on touchmove as this will prevent scrolling. Blocking default browser behavior can be very problematic for everybody.
3. Adding console logging like I did can help you debug issues, that might be the best way to figure out if the issue is the event dispatch itself or something that you've done on the page (e.g. overlapping elements).

Comment: You can check out the more advanced version of your previous answer that I created https://jsfiddle.net/4apd6to0/2/. I added an alert box within the touchend function and nothing happens. The alert box is not fired on release. Using my android phone for testing purpose.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987706/touchend-event-doesnt-work-on-android?rq=1

Comment: The touchend event doesn't function on Targets of Window, checkout the [TouchEnd documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchend). I've also made some recommendations with comments [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4apd6to0/3/).

Comment: The target is of type document / element

Comment: Great comments in the jsfiddle by the way. So I replaced it with only globals.target and it doesnt work either. I mean I explicitly set only an element from my object literal and not a window target.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an Android device to help debug the issue. But if the touchend event is buggy on Android then you may need to explore options such as playing with preventDefault and recreating default functionality or using different behavior for devices where touchend is failing...welcome to the pain of HTML development :)

Comment: Hehe ya. I tried preventDefault before posting the question. I added it within touchmove and touchstart. (e.preventDefault) but no change whatsoever

Comment: Hey cynicaljoy! I found out the solution!

Comment: After a lot of testing I tried this: https://jsfiddle.net/4apd6to0/9/ and guess what? Both touchend and touchcancel need to be called in order to work on android below version 6

Comment: That's great, you should add an answer and accept it so others don't have to read through the comments -- make sure to add details as to why you had to do it this way and what versions of Android you tested